# Parsing stringified array fields when reading csv files with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a csv file dumped from a DataFrame that had array fields, which looks like below:

```
col1,col2,col3    
"[454.40145382, 254.9620727, 0.9147141790444601]",2.1299914162447497,-29.85771596074138
```

When I read this back with `pd.read_csv`, col1 is parsed as a string by default. Is there a standard way I can specify for such fields to be parsed into numpy arrays whenever possible?

Alternatively, is there a numpy built-in that handles string arrays? I did not have much luck with `np.fromstring`, which complains about

> ValueError: string size must be a multiple of element size

My workaround is simply doing it myself with something like below (can be modified to be recursive for 1D+)

```
data["col1_parsed"] = data["col1"].apply(lambda x: [float(e.strip().replace("[","").replace("]","")) for e in x.split(",")])
```

But it feels too simple and tedious for it to not be handled by some builtin already

Comment: This has come up often.  `csv` is not a good format for saving this kind of frame.  `csv` is a 2d file format.  As you note the list has been saved as a string.  Since it is a list (with commas) some sort of `eval` should work.  If it was an array in the original, it wouldn't gave commas (the str of an array), and require more detailed conversion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `eval` if you trust the origin of data or `ast.literal_eval` (which should be better)

```
import ast

# df = pd.read_csv('data2.csv', converters={'col1': eval})
df = pd.read_csv('data2.csv', converters={'col1': ast.literal_eval})
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                                              col1      col2   col3    
0  [454.40145382, 254.9620727, 0.9147141790444601]  2.129991 -29.857716

>>> df.loc[0, 'col1']
[454.40145382, 254.9620727, 0.9147141790444601]

>>> type(df.loc[0, 'col1'])
list
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a converter could be a good fitting

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def convert_to_numpy(arr_str):
    return np.fromstring(arr_str.strip("[]"), sep=',')

dataframe = pd.read_csv('dataframes.csv', converters={'col1': convert_to_numpy})
```